# How to keep gif background transparency after do imagecropauto

Tags: php, image, gif, gd

I'm trying to auto crop a gif but it always fill the background...

My code:

```
$img = imagecreatefromgif($file);

$cropped = imagecropauto($img, IMG_CROP_TRANSPARENT);

if ($cropped !== false) {
    imagedestroy($img);
    $img = $cropped;
}
                    
imagegif($img, $file . "output.gif");
imagedestroy($img);
```

Result: [Screenshot of 1st result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPGxb.png)

And my temporary solution is: I fill the background with white color and the auto crop it.

My code:

```
$img = imagecreatefromgif($file);

$clr = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $clr);

$cropped = imagecropauto($img, IMG_CROP_WHITE);
if ($cropped !== false) {
    imagedestroy($img);
    $img = $cropped;
}

imagegif($img, $file . "output.gif");
imagedestroy($img);
```

Result: [Screenshot of 2nd result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gHN8.png)

But I need it be transparent... Could someone help me with it?